# Spring REST Docs configuration not working - java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-test, spring-restdocs

@AutoConfigureRestDocs and @AutoConfigureMockMvc do not configure MockMvc correctly. Even manually configuring them do not seem to help.

I tried configuring the MockMvc and MockMvcRestDocumentationConfigurer also manually, but it did not help.

This is the current setup:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(properties= "spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true")
@AutoConfigureRestDocs
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class LoginLogoutTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void adminCanLoginLogout() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(formLogin().user(TestConfig.ADMIN_USERNAME).password(TestConfig.PASSWORD))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(authenticated().withUsername(TestConfig.ADMIN_USERNAME))
            .andDo(document("login"));

        mockMvc.perform(logout())
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(unauthenticated())
            .andDo(document("logout"));
    }

}
```

I also tried configuring them with something like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(properties= "spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true")
public class LoginLogoutTest {

    @Rule
    public JUnitRestDocumentation restDocumentation = new JUnitRestDocumentation("target/generated-snippets");

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context)
          .apply(documentationConfiguration(this.restDocumentation))
          .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void adminCanLoginLogout() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(formLogin().user(TestConfig.ADMIN_USERNAME).password(TestConfig.PASSWORD))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(authenticated().withUsername(TestConfig.ADMIN_USERNAME))
            .andDo(document("login"));

        mockMvc.perform(logout())
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(unauthenticated())
            .andDo(document("logout"));
    }

}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: REST Docs configuration not found. Did you forget to apply a MockMvcRestDocumentationConfigurer when building the MockMvc instance?
```

What am I doing wrong? The error message is not very informative.

Comment: To avoid anyone wasting time trying to answer this, it was also cross-posted to the REST Docs issue tracker on GitHub: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/issues/655. The root cause is a bug/limitation of Spring Security and the request builder created by `formLogin()`.